# Block as an argement of the block

Tags: ios, block

I wonder if it's possible to declare/pass `block` as an argument of another `block`.

Let me illustrate via code and simple (not real) use-case:

- Assume that `ViewController` fetched list of objects aka `items` via `ItemsAPI`
- `ViewController` would like to display pins on `mapView`
- When `mapView` pin is tapped (selected):

  - `MapView` to display item should request for item details
  - When item details is loaded `mapView` updates it's callout or whatever

Code now:

```
// MapView.h

typedef void(^FetchItemCompletion)(id item);
typedef void(^ShouldFetchSingleItem)(NSInteger itemID, FetchItemCompletion(id item));


@interface MapView : MKMapView

- (void)pinItems:(NSArray *)items shouldFetchSingleItem:(ShouldFetchSingleItem)shouldFetchSingleItem;

@end
```

Implementation

```
- (void)pinItems:(NSArray *)items shouldFetchSingleItem:(ShouldFetchSingleItem)shouldFetchSingleItem {

    // For simplifying I'm using one method instead publishing mapViewDelegate and assigning blocks to self
    // 1) Pin items
    // 2) Some item seleceted - aka didSelectAnnotation
    // 3) We need to define WHAT WILL HAPPNED when we get item details
    FetchItemCompletion fetchItemCompletion = ^void(id item) {
        // update callout or whatever
    };

    // 4) Request for item details with fake id - 1
    shouldFetchSingleItem(1, fetchItemCompletion);
    // 5) ViewController should fetch item thorough API and then execute block (simply some mapView code)

}
```

So that ViewController would be able to do following

```
[mapView pinItems:items shouldFetchSingleItem:^(NSInteger itemID, FetchItemCompletion fetchItemCompletion) {
        // request to API or whatever
        id item = ...
        fetchItemCompletion(item);
    }
```

Getting errors:

[image]

Is this possible somehow and what is memory policy for this? Is there any bottlenecks or any other possible issues.

**Note:** appreciated answer to original question, not about sample use-case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second typedef needs to be declared as

```
typedef void(^ShouldFetchSingleItem)(NSInteger itemID, FetchItemCompletion fetchItemCompletion);
```

You don't need to redeclare what parameters your block takes when you use it as a type after you typedef it.

Comment: omg... kind of misspelling, so it works as expected, never used blocks like this. thank you